# Calling Stored Proc with CHAR Parameters results in a parameter with a huge value

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-5

I am calling a stored proc [MS SQL] using EF5 from a .net application

The call from EF

```
return base.ExecuteFunction<sp_select_contracts_Result>("sp_select_contracts", x, y, z);
```

in the proc the parameter is defined as `@para1 CHAR(2)` etc

But in SQL Profiler I caught EF sending the following

```
exec [dbo].[sp_select_contracts_statistics] @x='15                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               '@y='24                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               ',@z='2010                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            '
```

Exactly like that - a huge amount of spaces after the actual value.

When I change the **CHAR** to **VARCHAR** it works correctly:

`exec [dbo].[sp_select_contracts_statistics] @x='15','@y='24,@z='2010`'

I could work around this easily, but I would like to know what I am missing 
here.

Update:
Forgot to mention that in C# all the values are strings.
In the last call from c# before going through EF the values are correct:
`x = "15" {String}` etc..

Edit2:
Changing CHARS to VARCHARS worked as expected. Would still prefer to know if this is a bug or just something we are missing.

Comment: And how are your parameters defined in your application? It's obvious that it's the application to pass all that spaces...

Comment: AH i forgot that part :/
They are all strings and in the last call before going through EF, the values are correct.

Comment: I don't know  C#, but don't the strings have a SIZE in those definition there? For example, when you define a char datatype you should precise the size as well: char(50), for example. If you don't do that the default size is 1. can it be that in  C# there is also a default size, smth like 8000, and if you don't define it explicitly, it uses that default size?

Answer (score 0):

When you define a char parameter, you have to define the max length otherwise it is going to do something weird.  It defaults to putting white space for all the other characters not defined for the full length of the max size. I'm guessing the max size default for EF for a char here is pretty big:

```
var parm = new SqlParameter("x", SqlDbType.Char, 2);
parm.Value = "15";
```

Comment: This may be true but I thought this should be done by EF not manually.

Comment: EF has no idea what the parameter type is for stored procedures.  You have to set that yourself.

Comment: Couldn't it infer the type? I mean it is defined in the stored proc and EF already gets everything else - the storedProc itself and its parameters and even its return type.
Am I missing something?

Comment: you are giving a string to run sql so it runs outside of ef.  it would need to hit master db to figure out in parameters but it can't do that for you since it might not have permission.  I assumed the default would be 50 characters not that large, but it just means you have to tell it everything yourself when calling a sp.

Comment: Problem with changing the designer is that everytime i refresh the edmx and the it will auto generate and remove my changes.